# Can't update from a generated diff changelog

Tags: liquibase

First of all, I'm using an npm library called **liquibase** to run Liquibase within Node.

So, I'm trying to use `diffChangeLog` to compare two databases and generate a changelog of their differences. The changelog is normally generated, but when I try to run an `update` using the generated changelog Liquibase responds with a validation error. Here's the output:

```sh
node_modules/liquibase/lib/liquibase-4.0.0/liquibase --changeLogFile=examples/common/migration.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mySchema?useJvmCharsetConverters=true" --username=migration --password=migration --classpath=lib/migrator/drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar --changeLogFile=examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml update 

Liquibase Community 4.0.0-beta1 by Datical
    Starting Liquibase at 17:54:32 (version 4.0.0-beta1 #6 built at 2020-04-20 18:23+0000)
    Unexpected error running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
         16 changes have validation failures
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-1::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-2::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-3::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-4::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-5::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-6::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-7::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-8::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-9::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-10::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-11::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-12::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-13::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-14::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-15::joao (generated)
              columns is empty, examples/DatabaseDiff/diffChangeLog.xml::1618001652047-16::joao (generated)

For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

And here is part of the changelog that is mentioned in the output:

```xml
<changeSet author="joao (generated)" id="1618001652047-2">
    <createTable tableName="FeaturedProducer"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="joao (generated)" id="1618001652047-3">
    <createTable tableName="PreVerification"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="joao (generated)" id="1618001652047-4">
    <createTable tableName="Producer"/>
</changeSet>
```

I also tried to use the SQL format for the generated changelog (named `changeLog.mysql.sql`), but it creates a bad SQL syntax, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USER ();
```

This raises a syntax error from MySQL. Which is right, I've tried running this query manually and the error is the same.

My guess is that Liquibase is not allowing me to create empty columns, but why?
I don't understand what's going on and there are not many results on Google.
Can anyone give me a hand?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a while we've found out the problem.

To debug the issue I raised two local databases with Docker and tried the same operation, it worked just fine.

So, it occurred to us that the reason we were getting this error could be due to user permissions. I've seen some people talking about it, that Liquibase can spit unusual errors when the user has insufficient permissions.

So I gave my user all permissions for that schema and it worked! Actually, we just went to another error, but it was definitely progress!

The error was just like this:

```sh
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:250)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1285)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:314)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:149)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:148)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:127)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:173)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:177)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:313)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:134)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:169)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:148)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:248)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:193)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:86)
        at liquibase.command.core.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run(DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:63)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog$1.run(DiffToChangeLog.java:176)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:149)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:148)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:127)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:119)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
        at liquibase.change.ColumnConfig.<init>(ColumnConfig.java:154)
        at liquibase.change.AddColumnConfig.<init>(AddColumnConfig.java:16)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.core.MissingIndexChangeGenerator.fixMissing(MissingIndexChangeGenerator.java:70)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorChain.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorChain.java:48)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorFactory.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorFactory.java:95)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets(DiffToChangeLog.java:279)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.printNew(DiffToChangeLog.java:203)
        at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog$1.run(DiffToChangeLog.java:125)
        ... 23 more
```

**Really bad logging btw...**

This `MissingIndexChangeGenerator.fixMissing(MissingIndexChangeGenerator.java:70)`  part caught my attention. Surfing through the web I found barely anything, so we thought: *Let's check the source code for that line*. On their GitHub, we've found the exact line of the exception and everything became clearer.

That error meant that Liquibase failed to retrieve some table indexes.
Taking a look at our database we were reminded that some indexes were actually foreign keys to tables on another schema. And the user we were using didn't have permission on that other schema. We gave the user all permissions for that second schema too, and BAM, it finally worked!

The lesson here is: *Liquibase has really bad logging*... Oh, and also, *never give up!*